# Blue Yeti USB Microphone with Chrubuntu 12.04

Tags: usb, microphone, chrubuntu

As the title says I'm using Chrubuntu on my Chromebox and I really want to use my Blue Yeti (which is supposedly driver free) microphone with it, but the only thing that shows up as an input is Internal Microphone, which is no use.

The light on the microphone is on but that's as far as I get.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Chrubuntu is not an official release from Ubuntu, we would have no idea if any package of kernels needed to by modified by the Chrubuntu team. You should report this issue in to their support channels.